# Hardware configuration within Azure App service

Tags: apache, azure, nginx, iis, cloud

I have an Azure App service ( Php ) , an I need to know :

- Is it possible to know which web server is used( apache, iis,Nginx ) ?
- If it is the case, how can I get this information  ?

Thanks,

Comment: Azure Web App on windows is using IIS, not sure about linux, tbh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you choose Windows OS while creating app service then it is IIS. You can get this information by capturing from tools like Postman or Rest Client extension of VScode. When you browse the app service before putting any codes into you can see the IIS page loading.